# Android Upgrade "send SMS function" in QuickContact

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract, android-contacts

When i set up Skype on Android and clik on phone button in QuickContact in default "Contacts book" system asks how to perform this action : "Skypeout" or "Telephone".
I want to do similar function with sending sms from QuickContact bar, what i have to do to make system ask for user's choise when they click on the sms button in QuicContact bar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add something to receive the sms intent, either an activity or receiver, with the appropriate intent filters.